How to toggle visibility of toolbar widgets
I would like to dynamically control the visibility of widgets in QToolBar.
Although I call setVisible on them, the widgets don't seem to render differently.
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QToolBar, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class AppWindow(QWidget):
    _timer: QTimer

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._toggle = False
        self._window_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self._toolbar = QToolBar(self)
        self._label_1 = QLabel(self._toolbar)
        self._label_2 = QLabel(self._toolbar)

        # init elements
        self.setWindowTitle("Test App")
        self._label_1.setText("label-1")
        self._label_2.setText("label-2")

        # init layout
        self._toolbar.addWidget(self._label_1)
        self._toolbar.addWidget(self._label_2)
        self._window_layout.addWidget(self._toolbar)
        self.setLayout(self._window_layout)

        # init timers
        self._timer = QTimer()
        self._timer.timeout.connect(self._on_timer)
        self._timer.start(2000)
        self._on_timer()

    def _on_timer(self):
        self._toggle = not self._toggle
        self._label_1.setVisible(self._toggle)
        self._label_2.setVisible(not self._toggle)
        print("toggled")
        

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = AppWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

main()


The QToolBar.addWidget() documentation explains it clearly: "Using QWidget::setVisible(), QWidget::show() and QWidget::hide() does not work". Get the QActions returned by addWidget() and set their visibility instead of those of the widgets.
